# PagingAndSortingRepository methods throw error when used with spring data jdbc

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

All the CRUD methods related to the `CrudRepository` are working as intended but when trying to use the `findAll` with paging or sorting an error is thrown. I am using the `Lovelace-SR2` release train. The class only has one field which is the `@Id`. According to the documentation Paging and sorting is supported. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/1.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories

```
// this throws error
Iterable<FirstAggregate> aggregates = repo.findAll(Sort.unsorted());

public class FirstAggregate {
    @Id
    private UUID id;

    public FirstAggregate(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public FirstAggregate() {
    }

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
    <version>Lovelace-SR2</version>
    <scope>import</scope>
    <type>pom</type>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
 </dependency>

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No query specified on findAll
at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.JdbcRepositoryQuery.determineQuery(JdbcRepositoryQuery.java:132) ~[spring-data-jdbc-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.JdbcRepositoryQuery.execute(JdbcRepositoryQuery.java:90) ~[spring-data-jdbc-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy55.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.example.demo.CommandLineRunner.run(CommandLineRunner.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:813) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
... 5 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE: Support for `PagingAndSortingRepository` landed in Spring Data JDBC and will be available from 2.0.0 M3` onwards.**

You are pulling in `spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc` but you tagged your question `spring-data-jpa`.

So you either have to pull in the JPA dependency if that is what you want to use.

If you want to use Spring Data JDBC the bad news is: [We don't support paging and sorting yet](https://jira.spring.io/projects/DATAJDBC/issues/DATAJDBC-101).

The documentation does not state that this is supported, although it does look that way. 
Paging and sorting is only referenced in the generic part that describes the general concepts of Spring Data.

See also: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1086

Comment: Hi in my case I follow the sample with data-jdbc with jooq using two interfaces, however, always try to determineQuery when call jooq implementation.

Comment: @JensSchauder: I am using latest release 1.1.7.RELEASE and as per [documentation] (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts) this release has the paging support. However, the application throws `IllegalStateException: No query specified on findAll`. Any clue what could be wrong?

Comment: @MaqboolAhmed You are looking at the general part of the documentation which describes Spring Data in general. 1.x does not support pagination. 2.0.0.M3 is the first milestone that includes that feature. As described in the answer.

Comment: @JensSchauder: Excellent, it worked. Thanks for the quick reply.